# Can I manipulate the css to make the sections centered?

Tags: css

At the bottom of my web site at http://clearwaterfloridabeachrentals2.imbookingsecure.com/ there is a nav menu and three boxes with images. They are not centered instead they are left aligned. What CSS code can I use to center it?

This is the CSS I have:

```
      .row-fluid {
          display: -webkit-box;
          display: -webkit-flex;
          display: -ms-flexbox;
          display: flex;
          }

     .textwidget {
         text-align: center
          }
```

Adding the .textwidget css fixed the three boxes but the menu is still left aligned. Not sure what code directly affects it.

Comment: Please provide the relevant `HTML` and `CSS`.

Comment: .row-fluid {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center
}

Answer (score 0):

use `text-align: center` on the element

Comment: This did work for the three square images but it did not change the footer nav menu location. Any ideas?

Comment: be more specific, what element (id, class) and what u want

Comment: I also noticed that it cause the logo at the top of the page to shift left.

Comment: <div id="black-studio-tinymce-4" class="widget widget_black_studio_tinymce">   <div class="textwidget">

Comment: Again, please edit your question with the relevant HTML/CSS code.

Comment: The css I added is all I can think of that deals with this section.

Answer (score 0):

Use text-align: center for the div wrapping the three images.

And make the table width="100%" for the nav menu

Comment: This helped with the boxes but the menu in the footer is still aligned left.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox only works one level deep:

flexible container and flexed child. So you need to make the menu a flex container too and then **justify-content: center** the child elements

Add **flex: 1** to the child elements when you need them spaced evenly.

But this may not work well in your design as it is rather nested.

Essentially your footer is a column of two flexible rows

- menu (row of 8 flexed columns which need to be centered on the row)
- copyright (row of 2 flexed columns which seem to need space-between)

React on this first so I can help you further with restructuring